# See if you can figure this out:

Tags: riddle

There is a story that a man and not a man,

did see and not see a bird and not a bird,

Perched on a branch and not a branch,

And hit him and did not hit him with a rock and not a rock.

***How is this possible***?

Comment: Were Schroedinger and Heisenberg involved in this somehow?

Comment: No, Heisenberg is not involved in this riddle, good try though.

Comment: Is it a dream? You dreamed about a man throwing a rock but in reality there were no actual physical objects. Just figments of your imagination.

Comment: Nope, incorrect :), the answer is actually really quite simple, a story in itself.

Comment: @natural ... Plato? Is that you?

Comment: @Rubio uhhhhhhh, noooooooo. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A eunuch who did not see well saw a bat perched on a reed and threw a pumice stone at him which missed.

Comment: @natural Was this an unbelievably lucky guess? Or a very well known answer to a well known riddle? Or just that the question was too vague and pretty much anything would have been acceptable?

Comment: This is an old riddle, apparently attributed to Plato, whose answer can be found online elsewhere pretty readily.

Comment: I’ll concede/disclose that I have a dog in this fight, a horse in this race, a bird on this branch, a squirrel in this yard, [a snake in the grass](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224995/i-dont-have-a-in-this-saying#comment480770_224995), etc., but … … … … … … … this whole answer seems a bit thin to me, and I especially don’t see how it even marginally satisfies the “And hit him” clause.

Comment: @stackreader Have you never heard this riddle before? It's well known, yes, but this also seems to be the only answer that really fits properly.

Answer (score 1):

> A man and a woman were somewhere near a tree. 
> The man saw a bird on a branch; he threw a rock at it and hit it. 
> The woman saw a squirrel on the ground and said, "Aww, isn't that cute?"

Answer (score 1):

Building on [the accepted answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52937/19765#52939), which [“can be found online elsewhere pretty readily”](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52937/19765#comment162471_52939) (for example, [here](http://goodriddlesnow.com/riddles/view/286)),

> A eunuch who did not see well
> saw a bat perched on a reed and threw a pumice stone
> which ***hit*** the bat. 
> However, the bat was transsexual,
> so the “And hit ***him***” clause is only half true.

<sup>[Not that there’s anything wrong with that.  $:)$ ]</sup>

Meanwhile, in a nearby sandlot, kids with good vision were hitting a pumice stone with a bat.  $\large :)$